# How to display a placeholder before the tableview cells get displayed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This questions is referencing just before a tableview fetches its data and displays its cells.

I've seen a few apps lately display a rough outline type image of the tableview cells for the brief moments before the populated cells get displayed.

How is this done?

Is a placeholder image used for the entire tableview or are placeholder type images rendered for each cell until the cell is dequeued?

Here are examples from Facebook and the fiverr app
[image: fiverr]
[image: Facebook]

Comment: Might be each cell has place holder view looks like lines , and hidden when actual data comes ....

Comment: check this https://github.com/samhann/Loader.swift/tree/master/Example/FBAnimatedView @grabury

Comment: https://github.com/gonzalonunez/Skeleton

Answer (score 9):

Create a separate `UITableViewCell` class where the content of the cell is a `UIImageView` that has some kind of placeholder image of what your cells will look like.  Populate the `UITableView` with those cells while your background request is being made.  When the request completes, start a table update in which you remove all the placeholder cells, then insert all the "real" cells.

Comment: Hey Scott. How would I distingue between the two via the DataSource?

Comment: If they are separate classes you could inspect the class to find out... or have the two classes implement a protocol that contains a method that responds differently and allows you to distinguish them.  Really, though, your data source should know which data has been loaded and which has not and can simply provide the appropriate cell class depending on whether or not that row has been loaded.

Answer (score 4):

According to me it would be better to add backgroundView to tableView.

write:

while searching /fetching data:

```
if results.count == 0{
    tableview.backroundView = emptyBlurView
    }
```

once data is received so before reload :

```
 tableview.backroundView = nil
```

Answer (score 4):

when start requesting on server show the place holder cell and network response are received show the data container cell. using a placeholder cell same as activity indicator.

FaceBook are using [simmer](https://github.com/facebook/Shimmer) effect for its placeholder cell.

**Pod**

https://github.com/malkouz/ListPlaceholder

https://github.com/Juanpe/SkeletonView